# jquery remove child element after a certain amount of child elements

Tags: jquery

I have a `<span id="chat_hist">` with child elements of `<pre class="chatHist"></pre>`. I want to delete the oldest `<pre>` first once there are more than 100 `<pre></pre>`

```
<span id="chat_hist">
   <pre class="chatHist"></pre> // <- start deleting from here once more than 100 <pre
   <pre class="chatHist"></pre> // <- second one to delete once it hits 100 <pre again
   <pre class="chatHist"></pre>
   ...
   <pre class="chatHist"></pre>
</span>
```

Comment: good. A good task to do. let us know when you come up with some code for that too. If you get stuck while writing that code let us know for help

Comment: @LelioFaieta I usualy agree with that, but the question is dead simple, it takes no time nor effort to answer it :(

Comment: this is not a write for me website. and your comment is supporting my assumption. It is simple and can be solved with a bit of researching online. OP is showing no effort at all. Where is the javascript code he has tried so far?

Comment: Yes. You're 100% right. I should wait before answering..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is [first()](https://api.jquery.com/first/) and [remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) functions.

Then you can simply do this in your main function (the one you use to add the `<pre>` elements for example)

```
if($('.chatHist','#chat_hist').length > 99) {
 $('.chatHist','#chat_hist').first().remove();
}
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki woops, I may be blind, but I don't see where it's wrong. Can you tell me please?

Answer (score 1):

Use `first-child` or `last-child` pseudo as per your requirement inside loop like below.

```js
function deleteLog() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('#chat_hist').find('.chatHist:first-child').remove();
    if ($('.chatHist').length > 0) { //Check condition 0 or 100
      deleteLog();
    }
  }, 1000)
}
deleteLog();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="chat_hist">
   <pre class="chatHist">1</pre> //  start deleting from here once more than 100 <pre
   <pre class="chatHist">2</pre> //  second one to delete once it hits 100 <pre again
   <pre class="chatHist">3</pre>

   <pre class="chatHist">4</pre>
</span>
```

Comment: Why do you use a timeout? The main condition is the number of posts, there's no notions of time in the op question. Am I wrong?

Comment: Example check every second if message cross the boundary of 100 limit if yes delete that.

Comment: @vincent-d without a timeout you'll check only on an event-binded basis like page load or click of a button.

Comment: Why not it's just sample. Open choice for OP .  Assume that it's live chat log.

Comment: @LelioFaieta Sure, but as an answer we're even more is a "do it for me" situation, you just told, and I agreed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#chat_hist .chatHist').size() > 99){
   $('#chat_hist .chatHist').first().remove();
}
```